# WPF treeview datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, hierarchicaldatatemplate

Let's say I have something like this:

```
public class TopicFolder
    {
        #region Constants and Fields

        private readonly List<TopicInfo> folderContent;

        private readonly List<TopicFolder> subFolders;

        #endregion

...
    }
```

How do I implement a data template for such type? Currently I have:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TopicFolder}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubFolders}" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TopicInfo}" ItemsSource="{Binding FolderContent}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TopicName}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

But this does not show any folder content. It seems that second's template DataType should be local:TopicFolder, but this is not allowed by WPF.

Any suggestions?

UPD : TreeView is bound to ObservableCollection<TopicFolder> this way:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Folders}"
```

P.S: It is definitely not a private/public/properties problem. I have corresponding public properties for posted fields. No binding errors in output, it is just not showing any FolderContent items.

Comment: what is exactly your error message ?

Comment: and doesn't it miss properties that encapsulate the private fields ?

Comment: It seems there is no error messages (can not find any in "Output")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

To show both sub-folders and content one can either use a `MultiBinding` or if you don't mind that folders and content can appear in a certain order I'd suggest using the [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), for that you remove your SubFolders and FolderContent and replace it with a collection of objects which implement the composite interface (read the wiki article).

Creating a property to merge the two collections, so you can bind to it, is bad practice.

Example for composite pattern:

```
public interface ITopicComposite
{
    // <Methods and properties folder and content have in common (e.g. a title)>

    // They should be meaningful so you can just pick a child
    // out of a folder and for example use a method without the
    // need to check if it's another folder or some content.
}

public class TopicFolder : ITopicComposite
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<ITopicComposite> children = new ObservableCollection<ITopicComposite>();
    public ObservableCollection<ITopicComposite> Children
    {
        get { return children; }
    }

    //...
}

public class TopicInfo : ITopicComposite
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Sure I have, forgot to post it

Comment: I greatly suspect that the problem lies elsewhere, the posted code does not exihibit any flaw as far as i can tell.

Comment: Maybe...But as I can see while debugging, FolderContent is always populated properly, I mean It is not empty...I thought second template is just invalid...